# Parsing a list of JSON elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

What I'm trying to do:
I'm trying to parse a list of json objects. I made a REST API that returns a list of JSON objects, formatted like this:

```json
[{"_id":"61d7aca1ae700aeb4f9f9470","username":"test","email":"test@test.com","hasConfirmedEmail":false,"password":"test1234","createdAt":"2022-01-07T02:59:45.408Z","updatedAt":"2022-01-07T02:59:45.408Z","__v":0,"type":"user"}]
```

and I want to get the username of the first one. How would I do this in Javascript & JQuery?

What I'm doing:
I've tried doing:

```js
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'localhost:3000/my/api/route',
    type: 'GET',

    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data) {
        // using err to visualize the data temporarily
        err.innerHTML = json.parse(data)[0].username
    },
    error: function(req, status, thrown) {
        err.innerHTML = thrown
    },

    timeout: 120000,
});
```

but that just returns: `[object, Object]`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I know, I didn't copy it from the API output, I manually wrote it.

Comment: I'm using jQuery.ajax to send a GET request and using a success function that passes in the data to handle it. The data is valid JSON, and does exist.

Comment: FYI, your URL is invalid (missing `http://` prefix) and GET requests do not require a content-type header (they have no content)

Comment: All you should need for this is `$.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/my/api/route").done(data => err.innerHTML = data[0].username)`. See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because the object is in an array indicated by the square brackets on each end you can access the first item by using the index 0, then get the username from the object.

```
data[0].username
```

Comment: I think the issue is that your data variable is not a string. The JSON.parse function takes a string representing an object and converts it into an abject. for example JSON.parse("[1, 2]")[1] returns 2